# How does a mmf behave in windows?

Tags: windows, memory-mapped-files

I created a file based MMF in windows. Then I made a 2gb view and checked how fast I could access the data by reading 4 bytes somewhere in the middle. It was pretty much instantaneous so obviously it couldn't have red the whole 2gb in a few milliseconds.

That got me curious, how does it work?

1. Does it wait for me to read something and then read that specific part from the file?
2. Does it load itself into memory in the background while the process is doing other things?
3. If It doesn't load itself into RAM by itself, does it keep the parts I've already red there as a cache?
4. Is it magick?

Comment: Conceptually, at least, it's option number one.  Though it is allowed to load some of the pages in advance, if it thinks you're likely to use them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When mapping a view, a mapping is created between your virtual address space and the pages on disk. No data is read yet.

Only when you try to access some data, the page(s) that are mapped to that memory address are read into the cache (a pagefault is generated which forces the OS to read the mapped page(s) in memory).

So, to answer your points:

1. Yes.
2. No, but the OS could be prefetching some data into the disk cache (which is not exactly the same as 'filling your mapped view').
3. Yes, and those might be written to disk in the background (and maybe even freed when needed).
4. Yes! :)